Nextjs revalidate flashes between old and updated data on aws amplify
I am building a Next.js app with wordpress headless cms that is static built with the revalidation functionality,  and deployed on aws amplify, However, when i make a change in my wordpress, it toggles between the lastest data and previous data each time i refresh.
Here is my function below, i expect that when i refresh my page after 2 seconds, it should give me the latest data without toggling with the previous data.
export async function fetchAPI(query = "", { variables } = {}) {
  const res = await fetch(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_WORDPRESS_API_ENDPOINT, {
    method: "post",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      query,
      variables,
    }),

    next: { revalidate: 2 },
  });

  if (!res.ok) {
    console.error(res);
    return {};
  }

  const { data } = await res.json();

  return data;
}

